# MYSQL: One Way Push von Internal (Intranet) to External Server

Tags: mysql, replication, synchronization

I am having troubles with `MYSQL SYNC`. 

**The Situation:**
A Database working Internal in a Company. Now a Copy of that should be accesible on a external Server.

**Problem:**
 We're allowed to make a Connection from Inside-> Outside but not from Outside to Inside. So MYSQL Replication doesn't work.
I could set up a SSH Tunnel from the Inside to the Outside Server, this is working.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks!
Elias

Comment: I am also trying to figure this out. Will answer if I do :)